# how do i get the values stored inside a gameobject from a script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
public class inventorySlots : MonoBehaviour, IDropHandler
{
   void Start()
   {
      if(transform.childCount != 0)
      {
         GameObject itemInSlot = transform.GetChild(0).gameObject;
         item item = itemInSlot.GetComponent<item>();
         Debug.Log(item.Slot);
      }
   }
}
```

```
public class item : ScriptableObject
{
    public Slot Slot;
    public int id;
    ...
}
```

```
public enum Slot
{
    equippableInHelmet;
    equippableInChestplate;
    ...
}
```

I am trying to get the Slot enum from the class item from the script, it compiles on unity but it doesen't print the slot enum, this is the error i receive:

> ArgumentException: GetComponent requires that the requested component 'item' derives from MonoBehaviour or Component or is an interface.

All the class properties are public, i have tried with the id also but id doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Unity, the `GetComponent<>` method can only fetch a class deriving from the `MonoBehaviour` or `Component` class. In this case, the `item` class does not derive from `MonoBehaviour`, instead, it derives from `ScriptableObject`.

##### How to fix

There are two ways that would work to fix this problem.

The first way that you can fix this is by changing the class in which the `item` class derives from to `MonoBehaviour`, instead of `ScriptableObject`.

The second, more complicated way to fix this problem is to create a variable to hold the `ScriptableObject`, instead of fetching it with `GetComponent<>`.
The code would look something like this:

```cs
...

public item item;

void Start()
{
   Debug.Log(item.Slot);
}

...
```

You should then assign the `item` variable in the inspector.

If you want to learn more about `ScriptableObject`, [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aPXvoWVabPY) is extremely helpful.